# Programm works faster in graphic shell than in command shell

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi

I'm using a Raspberry Pi model B with a raspbian and kernel 3.18.
What I do is just going through a loop with execution calculation.

Loop function looks like this.

```
for(;;) {
   Timer.get_dt();
   ...some print stuff...
}
```

and `Timer.get_dt()` is:

```
oldtime_ = time_;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time_);
Timer.dt = ((static_cast<int64_t>(time_.tv_sec) * 1000000000 + static_cast<int64_t>(time_.tv_nsec)) - (static_cast<int64_t>(oldtime_.tv_sec) * 1000000000 + static_cast<int64_t>(oldtime_.tv_nsec))) / 1000000000.0;
```

when I run code from command shell, I get loop running at 300-350 Hz. When I go startx and open a graphic shell, open a terminal and run code from there, I get hundreds times bigger frequency which seems much more believable.

What can cause command shell run program so slow?

Comment: Output to a terminal, either the Linux native terminal or a X Window terminal emulator, have always been traditionally slow. it also depends other other things, like if you're connected over network, internal bufferings and terminal modes, and many other things.

Comment: To really see how slow the output really is, I suggest you try to check printing without buffering, the default line buffering used for `stdout`, and with full buffering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if you are using the command shell thru `ssh` or by plugging a physical screen device into your board.

Some virtual consoles have a baud limitation; so the kernel might try to imitate some slow terminal (including its speed). And virtual consoles (and any other `tty`-s) are traditionally slow.

You might use `stty` to understand and modify your terminal settings (in your virtual console).

BTW, it is probable that if you redirect the *stdout* (and/or *stderr*) output to some file, your program would go faster.